# Change controlling terminal

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, process, terminal

I came up with something like this..

```
int main (unsigned argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("***this is the original terminal window!!!***\n");
    if(!fork()){//child
        system("gnome-terminal -e ./client");
    }
    else{         
        printf("this is the parent, printing in the original terminal window\n");
    }
}
```

It opens a new terminal window where ./client is executed. The only problem is that the new terminal window closes automatically after the ./client thing ends. How can I fix this without doing something silly as using `for(;;)` on ./client? Furthermore this whole method is less than an optimal solution...

What I **really** would like to be able to do is this:

```
int main (unsigned argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("***this is a generator!!!***\n");
    if(!fork()){//child
        system("gnome-terminal or wathever"); //the solution must be here right??
        printf("this get's printed on the new window and whatever i do on the\
                child process get's done there too")
        //and the window won't close automatically
    }
    else{         
        printf("this is the parent, printing in the original terminal window\n");
    }
}
```

It would be more flexible and I would just prefer not having to `exec()` from another file...

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and the language is C.

Comment: As far as the first part: You could always just put a pause after the client (e.g. `client; read foo`) to keep the terminal open. As for launching a terminal and gaining access to its `pty` … I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should disconnect the child from its parent using `setpgid()`.

[From Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group):

The system call setpgid() is used to set the process group ID of a process, thereby either joining the process to an existing process group, or creating a new process group within the session of the process with the process becoming the process group leader of the newly created group. POSIX prohibits the re-use of a process ID where a process group with that identifier still exists (i.e. where the leader of a process group has exited, but other processes in the group still exist). It thereby guarantees that processes may not accidentally become process group leaders.

Answer (score 0):

`xterm` has a `-S` option which allows it to inherit a slave terminal from a pre-existing process, so I think you could do something like

```
main(){
    if(!fork()){
        int master, slave;
        char slvname[BUF_SIZ];
        openpty(&master, &slave, slvname, NULL, NULL);
        if(!fork()){
            execlp("xterm", "xterm", "-S", slvname, NULL);
        }
        write(master, "new term\n", 9); //or do you write to the slave?
    }
    printf("original term\n");
}
```